# How to save a 1-channel array as an image with proper color limit

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I am trying to save a sequence of 1-channel array into grayscale images. These images are supposed to be masks for segmentation.

The issue I am facing is inconsistent colors for same pixel value in different images:

Image #1
[image: image 1]

When I add additional circles to this image, then saved image has different set of colors for previous present circles.

Image #2
[image: image 2]

Ideally I want them to have consistent colors throughout my entire dataset as each circle represent a unique class of label.

So my question is how can I save these grayscale images with consistent color code?

Added code snippet to generate above image

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

image = np.zeros(shape=[256, 256], dtype=np.uint8)

cv2.circle(image, center=(50, 50), radius=10, color=(2, 2), thickness= -1)
cv2.circle(image, center=(100, 100), radius=10, color=(3, 3), thickness= -1)
cv2.circle(image, center=(150, 150), radius=10, color=(4, 4), thickness= -1)
cv2.circle(image, center=(75, 200), radius=10, color=(5, 5), thickness= -1)
cv2.circle(image, center=(200, 89), radius=10, color=(6, 6), thickness= -1)

# additional circles (they are part of Image #2)
cv2.circle(image, center=(21, 230), radius=5, color=(7, 7), thickness= -1)
cv2.circle(image, center=(149, 250), radius=5, color=(12, 12), thickness= -1)

mpimg.imsave('image.jpg',image)
```

Comment: If your image in in color then you have a 3 channel image not 2. If your image is grayscale, then you have 1 channel.

Comment: Why are you using _another_ library to save the image? What's wrong with opencv's [imwrite](https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gabbc7ef1aa2edfaa87772f1202d67e0ce)? Also, be aware you are saving the image as a (lossy) compressed jpeg.

Comment: When I use opencv imwrite, it saves this one channel array into mostly black image. I want to use this image as a masked label for my neural network model.

Comment: You are using very low intensity values, they are very close to `0` (black) against an all-black background - that's why you hardy see any circles. Use intensities close to `255` (white) to have a better contrast. Also, you are only setting two channels of the three, if you want color in your image you need a three-channel image and need to set three colors according to what you want. Remember, they are *BGR* images - one channel per color. Grayscale images use only one channel, not two.

Comment: Beware that matplotlib silently scales and applies a color map to your image, so what you are seeing is not you real image but matplotlib's _version_ of it, which is not at all optimal.

Comment: There is a reason to use this. So my question is how can I save such a low intensity pixel value one channel image in grayscale? I am okay with any process or using any other package or library for this.

Comment: You cannot use JPEG format for classification data. JPEG is a lossy format for ***photographs*** and is allowed to change your pixels for something that *"looks pretty similar"* but will be different when you re-read it. Use lossless PNG format.

Comment: Save masks as .png. if you WANT to save small integer numbers then they will be close to black. You can normalize them for displaying, if you want to see more contrast, but then you won't see the actual real values during displaying. You can also create a custom color-map, for example to map value 1 to red, value 2 to light-green, value 3 to yellow, or whatever you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First some tips...

- You cannot use JPEG format for classification data. JPEG is a **lossy** format for **photographs** and is allowed to change your pixels for something that *"looks pretty similar"* but will be different when you re-read it. Use lossless PNG format for class data. See demonstration at end of answer.
- Your classes are each represented by a single number at each pixel location - that means you need a single-channel image, a.k.a. greyscale. That means you should specify colours as a single number when drawing circles, rather than as a tuple of 2 numbers.
- There's no point introducing unnecessary dependencies - you are already using **OpenCV** so read and write your images with that.

These mean your code should look more like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

image = np.zeros(shape=[256, 256], dtype=np.uint8)

cv.circle(image, center=(50, 50), radius=10, color=2, thickness= -1)
cv.circle(image, center=(100, 100), radius=10, color=3, thickness= -1)
cv.circle(image, center=(150, 150), radius=10, color=4, thickness= -1)
cv.circle(image, center=(75, 200), radius=10, color=5, thickness= -1)
cv.circle(image, center=(200, 89), radius=10, color=6, thickness= -1)

# additional circles (they are part of Image #2)
cv.circle(image, center=(21, 230), radius=5, color=7, thickness= -1)
cv.circle(image, center=(149, 250), radius=5, color=12, thickness= -1)

cv.imwrite('classes.png', image)
```

This will save your images with very low contrast - all pixels will be in the range 0..12 out of a possible range of 0..255, so they will be dark, but still contain the information you need.

[image]

---

In order to visualise, you will need to contrast-stretch, or normalise your data to the full range. You can do that with **ImageMagick** very simply:

```
magick classes.png -normalize classes-norm.png
```

[image]

If you don't want to use **ImageMagick** to normalize, the equivalent operation in **OpenCV** is:

```
normalizedImg = cv.normalize(img, None, 0, 255, cv.NORM_MINMAX)
```

---

If you want to apply your own colormap to the data, you can do that using a LUT *"Lookup Table"* like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

if __name__ == "__main__":

   # Check filename supplied
   if len(sys.argv) != 2:
      sys.exit('Usage: argv[0] filename')

   # Read greyscale class image
   image = cv.imread(sys.argv[1], cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

   # Create a 256 entry palette each with 3 (RGB) entries, initially looking like greyscale
   pal = np.fromfunction(lambda i,j: i, (256,3), dtype=np.uint8)

   # Overwrite any desired colours from grey to new colour
   pal[0] = [0,0,0]      # 0 maps to black
   pal[1] = [255,0,0]    # 1 maps to red
   pal[2] = [0,255,0]    # 2 maps to green
   pal[3] = [0,0,255]    # 3 maps to blue
   pal[4] = [255,255,0]  # 4 maps to yellow
   pal[5] = [0,255,255]  # 5 maps to cyan
   pal[6] = [255,0,255]  # 6 maps to magenta
   pal[7] = [128,0,0]    # 7 maps to dark red
   pal[8] = [0,128,0]    # 8 maps to dark green
   pal[9] = [0,0,128]    # 9 maps to dark blue

   # Convert LUT to BGR order for OpenCV
   pal = pal[:,::-1]

   # Look up each pixel in the LUT
   result = pal[image]

   # Save result
   cv.imwrite('result.png', result)
```

[image]

Obviously you could equally store the LUT in a JSON or a CSV and load it from there rather than putting it in the Python code.

---

Note that the circle corresponding to class 12 doesn't show up because I was too lazy to remap that away from the dark grey I set in the default LUT (12,12,12).

Note that the image as colourised above is now a 3-channel RGB image, in contrast to the single channel, greyscale `classes.png`.

---

Note that you will need to revisit the code if you exceed 255 classes and use `np.uint16` and so on.

---

Here's a little demonstration of what JPEG does to your data. First we generate a 100x100 image and fill it with random noise, i.e. random colours. Then reduce the number of colours to 64 and save the result first as a PNG, and then save the same data again as JPEG:

```
magick -size 100x100 xc: +noise random -colors 64 -write a.png a.jpg
```

**PNG**

[image]

**JPEG**

[image]

They look the same, don't they. Now let's count the number of unique colours in each:

```
magick a.png a.jpg -format "%f: %k\n" info:
```

**Result**

```
a.png: 64
a.jpg: 9682     # OOPS! Look what JPEG did.
```

Why does JPEG do that? Because the file is 60% smaller but the images look the same:

```
-rw-r--r--@    1 mark  staff     46256  9 Jun 11:04 a.png
-rw-r--r--@    1 mark  staff     18991  9 Jun 11:04 a.jpg
```